# Fancybox and JW Player - stopping the video in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jwplayer

I'm embedding JW Player inside a Fancybox frame. What I'd like to have happen is the video stop playing/loading if the frame is closed. The code, and everything else that I've tried, works in Chrome but never in IE and FF.

What I have currently:

```
$('.lightbox').fancybox({
    //href: jThis.attr('href'),
    type: 'inline',
    padding: 15,
    width: 960,
    height: 540,
    autoSize: false,
    scrolling: 'no',
    enableEscapeButton: true,
    afterClose: function() {$("#large-video").empty();} //This is what I've tried changing
});
```

That bottom line, I've tried also just doing "jwplayer().stop()" and "function() {jwplayer().stop()};. Both work just fine in Chrome, but the video continues playing in IE9 and FF. Rather at a loss here. Anyone done this before?

Comment: what version of fancybox?  `enableEscapeButton` is not a valid option neither for v1.3.4 or v2.x .... additionally, inline video is not a good idea : why don't link directly to the video (and use fancybox media if using v2.x)?

Comment: Looks like fancybox 2.0.5. Sorry, the enableEscapebutton was a leftover, I have removed that. I always commented out the type: override. Neither made any difference.

Comment: why don't link directly to the video (and use fancybox media if using v2.x)?

Comment: .... or check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8772837/1055987 for a solution out of inline content.

Comment: A few days after but, I used a variation on the inline content solution you linked to and it worked. Can't mark your comment as the answer, but thanks.

Comment: ... but you could up vote my other post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The fix was to stop JWPlayer, then to `empty()` and `remove()` the DOM element containing it.  As in:

```
jwplayer().stop();
$("#container").empty().remove();
```

where `#container` is a div containing the player.  If you want to play the video again, you would have to re-instantiate the player in the DOM.

Comment: This works perfectly...in Chrome. In IE9 and FF the video still plays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to used the jwplayer method .remove() in your teardown code. simply deleting the lightbox elements is not enough.

**Taken from JWPlayer api docs.**

> **.remove()** Being the reverse of the setup() call, this call will remove a JW Player from the page. It ensures the player stops
>   playback, the DOM is re-set to its original state and all event
>   listeners and timers are cleaned up. Any listeners will need to be
>   reinstantiated if another player is set up.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#remove

This will also fix a related issue (this is the one I was encountering) where by player situated in a lightbox fails to load on the second attempt at launching it.

note: the error in this instance will be:

There was an error calling back an event handler for "ready". Error: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null
jwpsrv.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null.